# Getting the first 3 item in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, openxml

I am doing a project now and transforming word documents to html documents.

I add the small part of XML file here as well,this file is going to be viewed in HTML format.

```
<w:p w:rsidR="001207E2" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="001207E2" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
                <w:numId w:val="5"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>First Item</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00AD36E6" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00AD36E6" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
                <w:numId w:val="5"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>Second Item</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00AD36E6" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00AD36E6" w:rsidP="004E414C">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
                <w:numId w:val="5"/>
            </w:numPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
            <w:t>Third Item</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

So,this is the XSLT code that i try to use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="w:document/w:body/w:p">
                <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl[@w:val='1']">
                        <ol>
                            <li>    <xsl:for-each select="w:r/w:t[position()&lt;3]">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

And this is the result of that code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat"><html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>First Item</li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li>Second Item</li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li>Third Item</li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li>Fourth Item</li>
    </ol>
</body>
```

Okay the problem here is that i dont want to select the 4th element in the list.I just want to get the first 3 of it.

But it doesnt work.

I am quite newbie with the XSLT so,basically i cant see the problem.I checked the few sources and this seems very logical to me.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your `w:t[position() &lt; 3]` predicates will pass because all of the `w:t` elements are in position 1 of their respective `w:r` elements.

Test instead the position of the ancestor `w:p` elements:

Change

```
        <xsl:for-each select="w:document/w:body/w:p">
```

to

```
        <xsl:for-each select="w:document/w:body/w:p[position() &lt; 3]">
```

Depending upon your actual XML and requirements, you might also want to incorporate `w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl[@w:val='1']` test into the `xsl:for-each/@select` tests.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer but it doesnt work as well.I cant figure it out this for an hours actually it is supposed to be so simple..

Comment: Sorry, but "it doesnt [sic] work as well" is completely inadequate feedback to provide, and the number of hours you've spent is even less useful.  To receive further help, provide a [mcve], including input XML that's *complete* and well-formed. Thanks.

Comment: Hello,Thank you very much it is working now.I fixed by trying your way but now i need something like between w:document/w:body/w:p[position() >45 and &lt;47] these between values will give me in the code what i want.Thank you very much.